# Basic Authentication for migrate plus - unable to authenticate

Tags: migrations, authentication-authorization

The XML feed I was using recently updated to basic authentication. I updated my YML configuration with the basic authentication plugin as follows, but nothing seems to work, also there are no errors.

YML config

`source:
  plugin: mymigration_url_xml
  data_fetcher_plugin: http
  data_parser_plugin: xml
  urls:
    - https://xml-feed-url-for-the-migration
  item_selector: '/title'
  authentication:
    plugin: basic
    username: xyz
    password: pass`

All help is appreciated.

Comment: If you're having trouble with the plugin you can alway stuff it in the URL itself: `https://xyz:pass@xml-feed-url-for-the-migration`

Comment: I trid making a request as you  suggested but still the same. I am able to send a request through postman so the webservice works. Not sure what I am doing wrong in the module

Comment: @Clive I found the solution to this, data_parser_plugin: XML only works for a local file or remote XML feeds that don't require authentication. In order to support authentication plugin use data_parser_plugin: simple_xml